# Getting the buildtime of a C-project using Makefile

Tags: c, makefile

I have a large C-language based project and I want to get the build-time of the same. The problem is if I use

```
time -p make
```

it does give me the build time for the entire project. However, I would need the build-data at the sub-directory build level also. Meaning, I am dealing with about 1000+ Makefiles.

**Is there any way through which I can get this sub-directory level build-time?**

Brute-force way, I am thinking like this. But, not sure how to achieve this also as of now.

Replace every 'make' with 'time make' across the machine. Is there a way to do this?

Any other way of approaching the problem is also much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

One way to approach this problem is to extract all build commands into a file, e.g.:

```
make clean
make --dry-run > build-commands.txt
```

Then you can filter `build-commands.txt` by source file path, execute the commands and measure the times.

For this to work, your recursive makefiles must invoke other makefiles using [`${MAKE}`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#MAKE-Variable) rather than plain `make`.

Comment: If OP _is_ using `$(MAKE)`, could they just redefine it either as something like `time -p make >> build-timings.txt` or as the name of a shell script to do the same?

Comment: @TripeHound That may be a good idea. `${MAKE}` is somewhat special, so I haven't tried changing it.